# Is it possible to change URL when returning View in the same time ? That is without redirecting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, redirect

In ASP.NET MVC I have a controller that looks somehow like this:

```
public class MyController{
    public ActionResult Index(){
        return View(new MyModel());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model){
        //do something
        return View("RegistrationConfirmation", new ConfirmModel());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegistrationConfirmation(ConfirmModel model){
        //do something else
        return View();
    }
}
```

User's workflow that I'd like to have is following

- `GET` page index. Returns view `Index`. URL: `~/My`
- `POST` data from Index page - returns view `RegistrationConfirmation` and send the user to right page `~/My/RegistrationConfirmation`.
- User `POST`s another data while on `RegistrationConfirmation` page so that `RegistrationConfirmation` gets called to process them.

Right now action method `RegistrationConfirmation` is never called because after returning `RegistrationConfirmation` view by Index action method URL stays `~/My` so the second post is processed by `Index(MyModel)` action method not by `RegistrationConfirmation(ConfirmModel)` action method.

How can I change URL along with sending the View so that the controller action that corresponds to the view gets called on `POST` back ? Or is there any other way how to ensure that corresponding controller is called?

---

*NOTE: I have really read more than 20 questions that seemed to be on topic before posting this one. I don't think perfect answer to any of them will give me solution. Please **read properly before voting to close** as duplicate.*

Comment: Html.Action method should give you the flexibility to proper action method you want to invoke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one in the view RegistationConfirmation

you can easily add the action and the controller which should be targeted in the Html.BeginnForm command...

```
   <% using(Html.BeginForm("RegistrationConfirmation", "MyController")){%>

    //form elements

   <%}%>
```

with this you exactly define which action and controller is going to be called

Comment: I had a similar problem last night.  This answer is how I fixed it.  In the BeginForm you can specify any controller and any action to process your POST.

Comment: Thanks! Worked. In my case I had to add an ID to the parameters of the url of the BeginForm as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942926/pass-multiple-parameters-in-html-beginform-mvc4-controller-action